# Simplifying conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a positive random variable with discrete distribution:
$$ X = 
\begin{cases}
    x_0 & \text{with probability } p \\
    x_1 & \text{with probability } 1-p
  \end{cases}
$$
where $x_1 < x_0$.

I want to simplify $\mathbb{E}_X\left[ f (X) \right]$ where:
\begin{equation}
f\left(X\right)=-\alpha X -\gamma\max\left(0,Z-X\right)
\end{equation} 
with $Z\geq 0$ and $\alpha,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}_X\left[ f (X) \right] & =  p \cdot f(x_0) + (1-p) \cdot f(x_1) = \\
& = -\alpha x_0p - \gamma \max(0, Z - x_0)p-\alpha x_1(1-p) - \gamma \max(0, Z - x_1)(1-p) = \\
& = \begin{cases}
-\alpha x_0p -\alpha x_1(1-p) & \text{if}~ Z < x_1 < x_0 \\
-\alpha x_0p -\alpha x_1(1-p)- \gamma (Z - x_1)(1-p) & \text{if}~ x_1 < Z < x_0 \\
-\alpha x_0p- \gamma (Z - x_0)p -\alpha x_1(1-p)- \gamma (Z - x_1)(1-p) & \text{if}~ x_1 < x_0 < Z\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$